# Unable to restore SSAS cube from files/folders at Olap\Data\

Tags: ssas, cube, database-restore

There is a situation where I need to restore the SSAS DB to previous date because date is missing after current deployment.

I have the fix for incorrect deployment but it will take 1 day to correct and refresh the cube with new changes.

I wanted to restore the ssas DB with previous copy which is taken backup from folder "...Molap\DATA"

Are these folders/files can be used to restore previous copy? OR let me know what are different ways to restore the ssas db?

Note: Since not taken backup, I do not have backup file (.abf file)

Comment: I figured out: The files under folder "Molap\DATA" are data files, not backup files. Backup files are under folder "Molap\Backup". we should have habit of backing up SSAS DB every day? or should have older version of project for deployment?

If do not have any of these options,  there is no other way to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out: The files under folder "Molap\DATA" are data files, not backup files. Backup files are under folder "Molap\Backup". we should have habit of backing up SSAS DB every day? or should have older version of project for deployment?

If do not have any of these options,  there is no other way to restore it.